# Sync Table selection and Select value with antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to create a component who display a Select(multiple) above a Table.

The Select value and the Table rowSelection.selectedRowKeys are the same state.

When i select/deselect a row in the Table, Select value are update.
When i select an Option in the Select, Table selection don't update.
When i deselect an Option in the Select, Table selection update.

I must miss something in the doc but don't find what

Here a CodeSandbox to reproduce : 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/dank-cherry-f10uf

How to sync Select action and Table action ?

Thanks for your help (and sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Found It just forget to add value in Select.Option